# Additional class to 'a' element in Wordpress menu (no jQuery)

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Is it possible to add a class to the 'a' element in wp menu? It's Bootstrap - trying to disable dropdown and make the parent menu links clickable. Adding custom css to elements applies on 'li' and I cannot use jquery because of a plugin.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
 <li id="menu-item-X" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-X">
  <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" aria-haspopup="true">
   About
    </a>
    </li>
```

So I need to change class="dropdown-toggle" to class="dropdown-toggle disabled" but all the 'li' and 'a' elements are generated which I cannot figure out how to influence

Comment: What do you mean that you cant use JQuery because of a plugin? most JQuery plugins are built to integrate with the JQuery library.

Comment: And if you are not accepting jQuery as a solution, **do not tag the question as such**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this using plain javascript, like this:

```
var nav = document.getElementsByClassName('navbar-nav');
var a = nav[0].getElementsByTagName('a');

for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++ ) {
a[i].className = 'dropdown-toggle disabled';
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/rwqwg309/2)

Comment: Alright jQuery wouldn't work any way because scripts like this only see elements that had been generated but navigation must be generated every time on load with wp_nav_menu array

Comment: @yadayada Please mark the answer as correct if it has helped you! Glad to help!

Comment: Thanks, it didn' t though - there is no way to pre-load main nav menu

Comment: just put the code I've posted within a window.onload = function() { // code // }, then it will be attached every time